# rsync suddenly hanging indefinitely during transfers

Tags: macos, rsync, nas

For the past few years, I have been using an rsync one-liner to back up important folders on my Mac Mini desktop (OSX 10.9, 2.5 GHz i5, 4 GB RAM) to a FreeNAS box (0.7.2 Sabanda revision 5266, Pentium D 2.66 GHz, 822MiB RAM [reported by the system, I think there's 1 GB in there]). I am running an rsync daemon on the FreeNAS box. Recently, these transfers have been hanging indefinitely. I have done the usual Google-fu and am unable to identify the source of the problem or a solution.

The one-liner is:

```sh
rsync -rvOlt --exclude '.DS_Store'                                  \
      --exclude '.com.apple.timemachine.supported'                  \
      --delete /Volumes/Storage/Music/Albums/ 192.168.1.100::albums
```

I have tried enabling `-vvv` and `--progress`, but there is no pattern that I can discern between what hangs and what doesn't. Heck, if I retry, the same file might hang at a different point during the transfer or not at all. A dry run (`-n`) does not always succeed either. The only "success" I've had is implementing a timeout (`--timeout=10`) and rerunning the command over and over. Eventually, I creep along, but with no guarantee of success and at a pace that is unacceptable. I've reached a point where I have one file that I can't get past.

The Mac Mini is connected to my router via 5 GHz. The FreeNAS box is wired into that same router on a 100 mbit port. When transfers are actually going, `rsync --progress` reports 2.5-4 MB/s. According to `--progress`, a hang is literally just that—no data transfer is occurring as far as I can tell.

I need help with both the diagnostics and the solution.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I'm experiencing the same problem. I've been using the same script for a year or so, and suddenly I'm getting partial transfers. If I run the rsync command manually, it seems to hang after an indeterminate amount of time. Version is 3.0.9 on all machines. I'm going to try rolling back to another version to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: 2018, and the problem still persists. Sometimes not even a `kill -9` kills rsync.

Comment: Unbelievable, this should never happen.

Comment: I have the same problem in 2020; I've tried almost everything suggested in these answers, to no avail.  I keep getting wild swings in reported transfer speed; a file will transfer at 100 MB/s and then the next file transfers at 8kB/s...  This is maddening...  I think I'm going to give up on rsync and return to using cp.

Comment: I've got a problem that sounds pretty much the same. It almost always happens 32K into the next file, occasionally at 0 bytes. And there's a non-solution: when I hit `Ctrl+Z` and type `fg enter`, the transfer resumes. It repeats for every large file, until the total of all files remaining to be checked/copied falls below about 150-200 MB.

Comment: I've had rsync hang on a file just over 100KB in size. I did try Ctrl-Z and fg, but rsync didn't actually seem to do anything when it resumed.

Comment: Removing the `--remove-source-files` flag was sufficient for me (I was using it in combination with `--dry-run`).

Answer (score 36):

I was having the same problem. Removing -v didn't work for me. My use-case is slightly different in that I'm going from source (EXT4) to ExFAT. The issue for me was that rsync was attempting to preserve device files and permissions, which ExFAT doesn't support. I was using the `-hrltDvaP` switches. The `-D` and `-a` switches seemed to be my problem. The `-a` switch translates to `-rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)`. The `-p`, `-g`, and `-o` switches seemed to be my root cause as rsync was barfing on one or all of those during runtime. Removing `-a` and specifying `-Prltvc` switches explicitly is working for me.

```
bkupcmd="nice -n$nicelevel /usr/bin/rsync -Prltvc --exclude-from=/var/tmp/ignorelist "
```

Comment: This (dropping p, g, and o) worked for me also. I was copying from a remote ext4 drive to a local btrfs drive.

Comment: same issue - answer helped me on debian buster copying from a zfs\nix file system to an exfat disk

Answer (score 23):

Try using **--whole-file/-W**.
This command disables the rsync delta-transfer algorithm.
That is what worked for us (WSL to OSX)

our full sync flags were **-avWPle**

(e was because we were using ssh, and that has to be the last flag)

Comment: I can't imagine doing that for multiple TB of data on a regular basis, even if it does literally solve the problem!

Comment: The W option did the trick for me.  Otherwise, it was hanging after few seconds.  I am rsync'ing from Windows10 NTFS (rsync 3.1.2) to Linux exFAT usb drive (rsync 3.2.3)

Comment: This didn't really help me, but it *did* cause `rsync` to generate different errors which I suppose is progress...

Comment: @MatthewDeNardo rsync will still skip files that have already been transferred. All `-W` does is turn off the rsync algorithm for incremental updates on individual files. If you are not transferring files that are being modified (e.g. you are just mirroring a software repository), this option will have no negative impact at all. Solved the problem for me.

Comment: Nice answer. note that `-a` already implies `-l`.

Answer (score 21):

I've been running into the same thing again and again and it seems to help if you drop the -v option (which is annoying if you need that output).

Comment: What is mind boggling is that (at least on OS X) there is a "--timeout" option, but no "--tries" option!

Comment: also to add, if you drop the -v option, how do you know if it hangs?

Comment: @Michael you can use strace to watch the calls made by rsync:  `strace -f -e 'trace=!read'  rsync ...` – however, removing `-v` did not solve my issue

Comment: @Michael add `--progress` if you drop `-v`. it will help to know if hanging

Comment: I still get hangs with --progress and no -v

Answer (score 15):

This happened to me when the remote device ran out of space. The error wouldn't show when `--verbose` option was used; turning that off yielded some STDERR output that explained that the remote device was out of space. When I freed some space, I was able to run rsync again with `--verbose` and everything went fine.

Answer (score 6):

Just had a similar problem while doing rsync from harddisk to a FAT32 USB drive. rsync froze already in less than a second in my case and did not react at all after that ... left it with CTRL+C.

Found out that the problem was a combination of usage of hardlinks on the harddisk and having FAT32 filesystem on the USB drive, which does not support hardlinks.

[Formatting the USB drive with ext4](http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=291) solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yes that seem to have done it for me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 6):

In my situation rsync was not actually failing.

I have regular server backups which transfers large files over 500GB+ and have `--append-verify` or `--checkusm` over `ssh` parameters specified.

What I have found upon analysis is that once the client side completes it's file checks then the server side checks start. Which means while the server is doing it's checks the client side *will appear hanged and frozen* - run `htop` on the server to rsync working away.

This is likely a non issue if `rsync` is run in deamon mode on the server and using the `rsync` protocol instead of `ssh` for transfers.

On related note, this very LONG wait would trigger SSH timeout and a `rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (254 bytes received so far) [sender]` error message, sollution is to add `ClientAliveInterval 120` and `ClientAliveCountMax 720` to  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this quite often on 3.0.9 on a directory with hardlinks, but it also happened on 3.1.3.

There is a nice analysis in [Debian bug 820916](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820916): when its internal sockets are congested with errors, `rsync` could go into a deadlock.

This might have been fixed in a [3.2 release](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.2.1) just a few days ago (Jun 2020):

> Avoid a hang when an overabundance of messages clogs up all the I/O buffers.

The only good workaround I can think of is, if the problem is not persistent, then put [`timeout`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) in front of it: `timeout rsync <args> <source> <destination>`, then retry. If it is persistent for you, you're the lucky one who can debug it :D

Answer (score 1):

It also happens when the user on target machine has not write permissions on target folder.
You can try giving write permission to others target folder:

```sh
sudo chmod -R o+w /path/to/target-folder
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the IPC (Intrusion Protection Component) in our firewall.  It sees all the TCP SYN packets as a flood attack and kills the connection.  I left a rsync over NFS session open and turned off the IPC for the servers firewall rule and it starting working again right away.

```
rsync -ravh /source /destination
```

When it happened I was not able to kill the rsync session.  It locked up the NFS mount and I would have to reboot the client machine to get it to work again.  The strange thing is it would copy some files over then all of a sudden stop.  It always seemed to stop on the same file.  So I was looking for file issues, permission issues, TCP offloading issues, tried removing the -v in the rsync call.  If you are having this issue at least in my case it even happened with a simple.

```
cp -rp /source /destination
```

So I knew then to start looking at other factors.  So if you have any sort of intrusion protection on a firewall or router between the servers you can try turning that off temporarily to see if it solves your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not "your" problem, but I stumbled upon this question when I was researching a similar behavior:

I'm observing "hanging" when the target site has too much io load. e.G. on one of my small business servers, when someone is resyncing his IMAP account and downloading large batchs of data and a backup job runs that writes his data.

In this situation I notice a steep drop in performance for rsync. Noticeable in a high load value in `top` on the target machine, even though CPU and Mem are fine.

Waiting for the process to finish has helped every time or interrupting and attempting the rsync at a later time again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and it was because I was running out of memory during the rsync. Created a swap file and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Had rsync hanging issue on Ubuntu 16. None of the options above helped. The problem was in the source drive (external SSD) which suddenly became faulty. I tried several disk checks, but all of them stuck. Ended up rebooting the system and disk suddenly became accessible again.

Comment: 16.04 LTS or 16.10?

Answer (score 0):

Holger Ohmacht aka h8ohmh / 8ohmh:

The problem lies in the filesystem buffer / usage of the interworking of harddisk/hw so far as I could investigate.

Temporal solution for local drives (eg. USB3<->HD) : A script which is polling the changing disk space. If no changing free disk space then rsync is stalled and has to be restarted

`cmd="rsync -aW --progress --stats --preallocate --super \
        <here your source dir> \
        <here your dest dir>" 
    eval "$cmd" &

    rm ./ndf.txt 
    rm ./odf.txt 
    while [[ 0 == 0 ]]; do
            df > ./ndf.txt
            cmp ./odf.txt ./ndf.txt
            res="$?"
            echo "$res"
            if [[ $res == 0 ]]; then
                    echo "###########################################"
                    ls -al "./ndf.txt"
                    ls -al "./odf.txt"
                    killall rsync
                    eval "$cmd" &
            else
                    cp ./ndf.txt ./odf.txt
            fi
            sleep 60 
    done`

Change `<source dir>` etc to your paths!

In my case it is always stalling by usage of rsync's `--preallocate` option (normally because of better disk performance and rescueing continuous blocks), so as long as the disk and filesystem drivers not reworked there just this solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a shell script that synced one machine to another using:

```
rsync -avzu --blocking-io -e "ssh" (long list of --excludes) homedirname $user@$host:/Users
```

and this worked beautifully for many years for two machines on local ethernet.
I tried it from one Ventura machine to another Ventura machine.
It transferred a few files and hung.

The rsync I am using is rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
installed by Homebrew, on both machines.

Tried various voodoo, e.g. `-W`, no joy.
then I took out `--blocking-io` and whee, it went just fine.